# Alternative for Canvas.drawText() in PrintedPdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf, canvas, pdf-generation

I had gone through this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#draw-content) to create a `sample.pdf` file which contains text.

But as this API provides method to write text using only `Canvas` class. So I can't able to **select** text (as we can normally do in other PDF files) from generated `sample.pdf` file (as it is treated as image). Also that text gets *pixelated* on max Zoom (because of course those are **images** of letters instead of **vector-like-texts**).

> **So my question:** Is there any way through which I can just write text
>   in PDF without **`Canvas`** in **`PrintedPdfDocument`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to generate some HTML, then [print it using a `WebView`](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html).

Or, you are welcome to use any number of PDF generation libraries. [This category in the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/72?sort=created) lists some, alongside PDF viewers and other utilities related to PDFs.

Comment: I have tried [this](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) and successfully generated the PDF, but the problem still persisted (Generated text is drawn text - like a graphics text - **not selectable** text).